# Triggering keystroke from javascript

Tags: javascript, autohotkey, keypress, keystroke

I have a simple html/js application, which will run locally.
If certain conditions are met, I need to simulate a keystroke (e.g. 'a') in a way that AutoHotkey program, which is running in the background, would register it and therefore launch a script.

Triggering jQuery keypress and such will not help, as it stays inside the browser and AHK, which runs in the background as a separate program, won't register it.

Is it possible to achieve this within js? If not, what would be the best way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to say that "*whats runs in browser stays in browser*" ...

but f.e. you can set clipboard value in browser and then use OnClipboardChange event in autohotkey to detect it.

Another way would be to use Flash / browser plugin / server side script (since this is localhost) / to modify some file and watch it with autohotkey.